# Small changes to existing jQuery Slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slideshow

I have tweaked this Slideshow script and am around 99% happy with it.

Current **DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/Qu3NK/4/

---

I just wonder, if I can possibly remove the integers ('**2** text goes here' & '**4** other text here') from my navigator divs & not break the slideshow at the same time. I guess I would need to change my code here:

```
$(".navigator").on("click", function () {
        alert("clicked");
        navigate_to(parseInt($(this).html(), 10));
    });
```

So ultimately, **my navigation would just be text and not include integers**.

Also, is there a way to **disable this slideshow from playing at the start**?

Comment: Does this work? http://jsfiddle.net/Qu3NK/5/

Comment: Hi Asad. No, sadly it doesn't. I need text inside the links to click. But I don't want the integers in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you store it in an attribute? For example, in HTML5 it's valid to use custom `data-` attributes:

```
<div class="navigator" style="font-size:30px" data-slide="2">text goes here</div>
<a class="navigator" style="font-size:30px;" data-slide"4">other text here</a>
```

You can then use this alternate code:

```
$(".navigator").on("click", function () {
    navigate_to(parseInt($(this).attr('data-slide')), 10);
});
```

If you aren't using HTML5 or don't want to take that approach, then do something like:

```
<div class="navigator" style="font-size:30px" id="navigator-2">text goes here</div>
<a class="navigator" style="font-size:30px;" id="navigator-4">other text here</a>
```

And then:

```
$(".navigator").on("click", function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    navigate_to(parseInt(id[id.length-1]), 10);
});
```

**EDIT:**

And to stop the animation:

```
stopAnimation();
```

Consolidated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Qu3NK/10/.

Comment: Oooooh, this sounds familiar. I will give it a try just now & report back - many thanks for your help here!!

Comment: Can you possibly try this yourself in a JSFiddle. I have tried your code, but it doesn't work for me. The links fail.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Qu3NK/8/ acheong, you just need to add parseInt or remove the 10.

Comment: Beautiful edit, acheong87!! It now works exactly as I wanted. Thank you, thank you!!!

Comment: Yes, sorry, I was trying to edit and provide a jsFiddle but Hurricane Sandy knocked out my Internet and my 3G tethering is unreliable.

Comment: Wow, you really went out your way to help - thank you so much. Please stay safe with Sandy too - godspeed.

Comment: Also, is it possible to disable the slideshow going through all the images? So it just loads the initial image but doesn't auto navigate through the others?

Comment: Yes, just add `stopAnimation();` at the very end of your ``ready()`` function: http://jsfiddle.net/Qu3NK/10/. And thank you for your well wishes.

Answer (score 1):

For removing the integers, why not just use an id attribute?

```
<div id="num2" class="navigator" style="font-size:30px">some text goes here</div>
```

Then you would access it with

```
navigate_to($(this).id);
```

If you *must* use a number, then use

```
navigate_to(parseInt($(this).id));
```

To disable it at the start, try wrapping all the Javascript in a function that executes under some condidtion, i.e.

```
$(".startButton").click(function{

    // All the slideshow code goes here.

});
```

Comment: Many thanks, apostl3pol. Is there a simpler way to disable the autostart of the slideshow?

Comment: Oh, I just remembered that you can't start an id with an integer. I've edited my answer to reflect that. For stopping the slideshow,@acheong87's stopAnimation() suggestion sounds like a good one. :)